# Convert difference between 2 dates into iso8601 duration in Ruby (and Rails if needed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to convert a couple (start_at, end_at) into an iso 8601 duration, with only 1 periodicity set.

For example:

1. 2023/03/01 : 2023/03/10 => **P9D** (9 days) and not P1W2D (1 week 2 days)
2. 2023/03/31 : 2023/04/28 => **P4W**
3. 2023/03/31 : 2023/04/29 => **P29D** (and not P4W1D)
4. 2023/03/31 : 2023/04/30 => **P1M** (because 03/31 + 1.month = 04/30)
5. 2024/02/29 : 2025/02/28 => **P1Y** (because 2024 is a leap year)
6. 2024/02/29 : 2024/03/29 => **P1M** (because it's the same day, the next month)

In case of ambiguity, I always want the bigger period to win.

For example:

- 2023/01/31 : 2023/02/28 => **P1M** & **P4W** would be both correct, but I prefer **P1M** because month > week

I know it's really specific, but maybe someone has an idea on how to proceed? This seems like a problem people has already solved. The only resources I've found on the internet were converting a duration (in seconds) into iso 8601, but it can't work for some of the special cases described before (for example, the 4th one).

Comment: Why is 2023/03/31-2023/04/30 one month, but 2024/02/29-2024/03/29 only 29 days and not one month and one day?

Comment: Because april has 30 days whereas march has 31 one days. I do understand that if you write `Time.parse("2024-02-29") + 1.month` you get `2024-03-29 00:00:00 +0000`... but also, if you write `Time.parse("2024-03-31") - 1.month` you'll get `2024-02-29 00:00:00 +0000`. NEVERTHELESS, I do agree with you and I'll edit my question.

Comment: Note that `1.month` does always return the same amount of days, no matter if the current month has 28, 29, 30 or 31 days. `1.month.in_days #=> 30.436875`

Comment: @spickermann it behaves different in calculations, e.g. `Date.new(2023,1,31) + 1.month` returns February 28th whereas `Date.new(2023,1,31) + 1.month.in_days` returns March 2nd.

Comment: Since I know a period won't be more than a year, I could check every cases like this: `case when start_at+1.year == end_at then "P1Y"; when start_at+11.months == end_at then "P11M"; ... +1.month == end_at then "P1M"; when + 51.weeks ...; + 1.week; + 30.days...; + 1.day`. But I don't think that's ideal and I would have loved to find something smoother (I know I could optimize the case/when with something like `(1..11).each {|month_count| if start_at + month_count.months == end_at then return "P#{month_count}M"}` but still, it can be a lot of tests before finding the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Days

I would start by calculating the difference in (whole) days between the two dates:

```
d = (to_date - from_date).to_i
```

If everything else fails, we'd resort to this as **P**`d`**D**.

##### Weeks

Weeks are always 7 days, regardless of months or leap years. We can determine a week-difference via `divmod`:

```
w, r = d.divmod(7)
```

If the remainder `r` is zero, the two dates are *exactly* `w` weeks apart, or **P**`w`**W**.

##### Months

Due to leap years and months having different number of days, I'd take a different approach for the remaining two cases. I would calculate the approximate number of whole months between the dates via: (30.436875 is the [average number of days in a month](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961090/mean-number-of-days-in-a-gregorian-month) when including leap years)

```
m = (d / 30.436875).round
```

And then check if this value happens to be an exact match:

```
from_date.next_month(m) == to_date
```

If so, we have **P**`m`**M**.

##### Years

For years, I'd take a similar approach:

```
y = m / 12
```

and check via:

```
from_date.next_year(y) == to_date
```

Which gives **P**`y`**Y** if true.

##### Conclusion

Everything in one method: (pure Ruby, no Rails)

```
def duration(from_date, to_date)
  d = (to_date - from_date).to_i  # number of days
  m = (d / 30.436875).round       # number of months
  y = m / 12                      # number of years
  w, r = d.divmod(7)              # number of weeks

  return "P#{y}Y" if from_date.next_year(y) == to_date
  return "P#{m}M" if from_date.next_month(m) == to_date
  return "P#{w}W" if r == 0

  "P#{d}D"
end
```

Examples:

```
duration(Date.parse('2023/03/01'), Date.parse('2023/03/10')) #=> "P9D"
duration(Date.parse('2023/03/31'), Date.parse('2023/04/28')) #=> "P4W"
duration(Date.parse('2023/03/31'), Date.parse('2023/04/29')) #=> "P29D"
duration(Date.parse('2023/03/31'), Date.parse('2023/04/30')) #=> "P1M"
duration(Date.parse('2024/02/29'), Date.parse('2025/02/28')) #=> "P1Y"
duration(Date.parse('2024/02/29'), Date.parse('2024/03/29')) #=> "P1M"
duration(Date.parse('2023/01/31'), Date.parse('2023/02/28')) #=> "P1M"
```

Comment: Nice and elegant, thanks 